# "Am I going the right way for Downwood?" versus "Is this the right way to the station?" Why the change of preposition?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, word-usage

Two sentences taken from *First Certificate Language Practice* by Michael Vince, 4th edition, p. 104, ex. 4, n° 3, and p. 105, ex. 5, n° 5:

"Excuse me, is this the right way to the station?"

"Am I going the right way for Downwood?"

(to be transformed into, says the key: "Is this the right way for Downwood?")

Why use the preposition 'to' in one case, and 'for' in the other? Aren't a town and a station two places?

Comment: I don't understand why the manual wants you to change "Am I going the right way for Downwood?" That's a perfectly fine question.

Comment: Neither do I, but that's how it is!

Comment: At first I thought the change of preposition was to do with the fact that it is "Am I going the right way?" in one case, and "Is this the right way?" in the other, but then the key reads "Is this the right way for Downwood?", so this cannot be the answer…

Comment: The sentence quoted as "to be transformed" is not _Am I going the right way?_ -- look again. If this isn't a typo, there's your error. If not, you have an incompetent textbook. Give it to somebody you don't like and get a good one.

Comment: @JohnLawler: the sentence reads "Am I going the right way for Downwood?" but I shortened it to "Am I going the right way?" because I wanted the reader to focus on the part of the question preceding the preposition, as a possible reason why you had 'to' in one case and 'for' in another. I should have used […] to indicate that I was leaving words out. My incompetence!
This book is the one all the (or zero article?) English teachers at my high school have agreed on.

Comment: In the (unedited) OQ, the sentence reads: _"Am going the right way for Downwood?"_ -- no ***I*** subject, you see. As Terry Pratchett is fond of pointing out, it's very hard to see what's really there, instead of what one expects to be there.

Comment: No proofreading or proofreading that was not foolproof! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

My inclination is to say that with

> Is this the right way to the station?

*You* are traveling to the station; whereas with

> Is this the right way for Downwood?

The *train* is traveling to Downwood, and you are looking for the train.  Within the station, you may be moving in every possible direction, including directly away from Downwood, in order to reach the train.  But the point is really that you are not going to Downwood directly under your own power, but rather seeking out something that will take you there.

Comment: But since the key gives "Is this the right way for Downwood?" as equivalent to "Am I going the right way for Downwood?", I doubt very much that the person is going there by train, don't you think?

Comment: Since the previous sentence talks about a station, the inference that a train is involved seems reasonable to me.  Of course I can't really know without better access to the source.

Comment: There just is not any context to these sentences, as is often the case in exercises in grammar books, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is parallel to the difference there is between 'going to a place' and 'heading for a place' or 'being headed for a place'?

A CD version of the *Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English* I have in my computer says 'heading for a place' or 'being headed for a place' is "going or travelling towards a particular place, especially in a deliberate way". And the adjective 'deliberate' is defined as "intended or planned".

So, the difference might be that:

- I have planned **an itinerary** to go to Downwood, which I am checking on,

whereas

- I have not planned one to go to the station: I am only going in **the general direction of** the station, which I am checking on too.